# Create postorder from tree in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to traverse a tree in postorder using LISP.

If the tree is represented like this: (A (B) (C (D) (E)))

I know that I could write this function

```
(defun postorder(l)
    (cond
        ((null l) nil)
        (t (APPEND
                (postorder (CADR l))
                (postorder (CADDR l))
                (LIST (CAR l))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

However, when the tree is represented in this way (A 2 B 0 C 2 D 0 E 0) I'm stuck.
Can anyone help me modify my above function to work for this kind of tree?

Comment: What is the output that you wanted?

Comment: I confess that I don't understand the question. I don't understand the format (A 2 B 0 C 2 D 0 E 0) . This might, ultimately, be a good thing. But it may also explain the lack of answers.

Comment: I guess that it is a list of _content_ followed by the number of children, which you then have to read in.

Comment: A good step would be to specify exactly how a list of that form represents a tree. If the integer is the number of children, how do you distinguish between `(A (B) nil)` and `(A nil (B))`?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the question thus: `(A 2 B 0 C 2 D 0 E 0)` should represent the same tree as `(A (B) (C (D) (E)))`.  The format is the content of the current node, followed by the children count, followed by … the rest.  The difficulty lies in parsing this, as you can't just recurse into the children, you also need to return the point where the outside parsing has to continue.

I would do this by returning that tail as a second value.  Here is a quick implementation:

```lisp
(defun postorder* (list)                                                  
  (if (endp list)
      nil                                                     
      (destructuring-bind (content n &rest rest) list                     
        (if (zerop n)
            (values (list content) rest)                        
            (loop :repeat n                                               
                  :for (child-po rest)                                    
                    := (multiple-value-list (postorder* (nthcdr 2 list))) 
                      :then (multiple-value-list (postorder* rest))       
                  :append child-po :into po                               
                  :finally (return (values (append po (list content))     
                                           rest)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may regard the `(A 2 B 0 C 2 D 0 E 0)` syntax as a stream of tokens. This is easily parsed by recursive descent.  A recursive descent parser for any language typically reads tokens from a stream, which is a stateful object that is global to the entire recursion, being passed down among the recursive functions, or perhaps stored in a global area. The stream solves the problem of moving the input position from one token to the next.

In Lisp, the list itself is easily used as a stream. For instance if we have a variable `s` which holds `(1 2 3)`, we can remove an item from it using `(pop s)` and other ways.  In some Lisp-related literature, lazy lists are even referred to as streams.

To write a recursive descent parser over a stream, we can make the recursive part a local function, which has the stream variable in scope; it can then mutate the variable to consume tokens.

Here is a function in a Lisp dialect called TXR Lisp which parses `(A 2 B 0 C 2 D 0 E 0)` and converts it into `(A (B) (C (D) (E)))`

```
(defun parse (syntax)
  (labels ((rec (parsym n)
             (cons parsym
                   (collect-each ((i 0..n))
                     (match-case syntax
                       ((@sym 0 . @rest)
                        (set syntax rest)
                        (list sym))
                       ((@sym @(integerp @m) . @rest)
                        (set syntax rest)
                        (rec sym m))
                       (() (error "abrupt end in syntax"))
                       (@else (error "unhandled syntax: ~s" syntax)))))))
    (cadr (rec :root 1))))


1> (parse '(A 0))
(A)
2> (parse '(A 1))
** abrupt end in syntax
** during evaluation of form (error "abrupt end in syntax")
** ... an expansion of (progn (error "abrupt end in syntax"))
** which is located at parse.tl:5
3> (parse '(A 1 B 0))
(A (B))
4> (parse '(A 2 B 0 C 2 D 0 E 0))
(A (B) (C (D) (E)))
```

The recursive parsing is done by a single function called `rec`. `rec` mutates the `syntax` variable by assigning to it. The two forms `(set syntax rest)` consume the matched prefix of the syntax, moving the list pointer to the unparsed remainder of the syntax.

The function takes two arguments: the parent symbol, and the integer value: how many children that symbol has.

There is a trick being done here to prime the parser: our top-level call to `rec` is `(rec :root 1)`.  We are pretending that the entire syntax we are parsing, such as `(A 2 B 0 ...)` has been embedded in a larger syntax `(:root 1 A 2 B 0)`, and that we have just parsed the `:root 1` part. Thus, we are telling the `rec` function: please parse out 1 argument node, and then create a `:root` node with that argument. What will then emerge from the `rec` function (given the example syntax) is actually `(:root (A (B) (C (D) (E))))`, and so we apply `cadr` to that to remove the wrapping to obtain just the `(A (B) ...)`.

How the function works is simple: it recognizes two possible prefixes, using pattern matching:

- an item, followed by 0, and the rest of the syntax; or else
- an item, followed by an integer other than zero, and the rest.

All other cases are syntax errors.  We don't check that the item is a symbol, so it doesn't have to be, or that the integer is positive.

The function does this in a loop: it iterates as many times as its argument indicates, to extract that many instances of the node syntax. The extractions are collected into a list, and the parent symbol is tacked onto the front with `cons` to produce the return value.

In the first case, when we have an item followed by zero, there are no arguments to extract for that node, so there is no recursive call. That iteration of the loop produces the matched symbol/item wrapped in a list. For instance, if `rec` is called as `(rec 'Y 1)`, and `syntax` contains `(X 0 whatever ...)`, then the loop will recognize the `X 0` case, and collect the value `(X)`, setting `syntax` to the remainder `(whatever ...)`. Because of the `1`, the loop will just iterate that one time, and so the list which is collected is `((X))`. The incoming symbol `Y` is tacked onto this to create `(Y (X))`.

In the nonzero case, we have recursion. When a syntax like `(Z 2 whatever ...)` is seen, we simply call `rec` with that extracted symbol and number as the argument: `(rec 'Z 2)`. This will execute is its own loop which extracts a two-argument node headed by the symbol `Z`, return that node to us, and leave the `syntax` variable pointing at the remaining syntax.